# Capture all unhandled exceptions automatically with WebService

Tags: c#, exception, capture

I have a C# WebService application in which I want to capture all unhandled exceptions thrown from the application.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

For some reason the Application_Error event does not fire for Web Services (see [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211530/why-global-asax-applicationerror-method-does-not-catch-exceptions-thrown-by-asmx)). Mr Jeff Atwood himself has posted some advice [on the coding horror blog](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000054.html).

He writes:

> * Put a try..catch around every WebService method. These methods tend to be wrappers around other classes, so this isn't quite as bad as it sounds, but it's still not good.  
>
> * use a Facade design pattern to derive all objects from parent objects that.. basically do a try..catch on the .Execute method. Uh, thanks but no thanks.  
>
> * Write a custom SOAP Extension or HttpModule. This sounds reasonable but.. hard. If it's such a cool, important extension or HttpModule, wouldn't someone have written it already?

Answer (score 1):

One way will be to subscribe to `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event somewhere in `App_Start` handler.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a job for an aspect-oriented approach.  Some examples;

[PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions/monitoring)

[Spring.Net](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/aop.html)