# Rewrite URL of ASMX Web Service

Tags: c#, url-rewriting, asmx, global-asax

I'm trying to map an incoming URL from an ajax request to a web service method in the Global.asax. 
The web service is in this path `/ajax/BookWebService.asmx`, it has 2 methods `GetListOfBook` and `GetListOfAuthor`.

I want to use  url: `/ajax/book/list` instead of url: `/ajax/BookWebService.asmx/GetListOfBook` in the Script tag.

Here's my script and mark-up:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function () {
      $("#btnCall").click(function () {

          $.ajax({type: "POST",
              url: "/ajax/book/list",
              data: "{}",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               dataType: "json",
              success: function (response) {
                  var list = response.d;
                      $('#callResult').html(list);
              },
              error: function (msg) {
                  alert("Oops, something went wrong");
              }
          });

      });
  });

</script>

<div>
  <div id="callResult"></div>
  <input id="btnCall" type="button" value="Call Ajax" />
</div>
```

Here's the Global.asax :

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var currentRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;

    if (currentRequest.Contains("ajax/book/list")) {
        HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("/ajax/BookWebService.asmx/GetListOfBook");
    }

}
```

When I check in FireBug console this is what I get :

> "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - localhost:13750/ajax/book/list"

If I change the *url: `/ajax/book/list`* to *url: `/ajax/BookWebService.asmx/GetListOfBook`* it works as expected.

I'm using VS 2010 and .NET 4.

How do I do ajax call to `/ajax/book/list` instead of `/ajax/BookWebService.asmx/GetListOfBook`?

Comment: Wouldn't the Web API be a more fitting tool for the task? You can post data to the Web API method, with javascript, and by default it will return as JSON (using the content-type). Same for xml etc... An example http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Comment: Yes, indeed. But I have a small project that was built with ASMX that need a way to keep clean callback URL.

Comment: If its a small project, shouldn't be difficult to convert over :P

Comment: Apparently this redirect correctly. Try that the method GetListOfBook  returns a List <int> or something, without logic. If redirection fails returns a 404  error

Comment: @Mate I did. But that method never gets called. It works if I call it directly.

Comment: you could catch the error in Global.asax with ... void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Server.GetLastError().Message);
        }

Comment: Also I did that. But no error at all. I even used RewritePath in the Try and Catch block. but no error.

Comment: Application_Error never fires for a web service. http://stackoverflow.com/a/211844/270536

Comment: I understand that the error occurs between RewritePath and before running the method, and not inside the method. Then Application_Error should catch the error. (eg if you invoke a page that does not exist, fires the Application_Error () and Server.GetLastError().Message returns "File does not exist"). I hope I can help ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can change the ajax call to type: "GET", try this changes:

Ajax call:

```
    $(function () {
        $("#btnCall").click(function () {

            $.ajax({ type: "GET",  //Change 1
                url: "/ajax/book/list",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    var list = response.d;
                    $('#callResult').html(list);
                },
                error: function (msg) {
                    alert("Oops, something went wrong");
                }
            });

        });
    });

</script>
```

Global.asax :

```
    void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var currentRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
        //Change 2
        if (currentRequest.Contains("ajax/book/")) // maybe you can use a generic path to all rewrites...
        {
            IgnoreWebServiceCall(HttpContext.Current);
            return;
        }
    }
    //Change 3
    private void IgnoreWebServiceCall(HttpContext context)
    {
        string svcPath = "/ajax/BookWebService.asmx";

        var currentRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;

        //You can use a switch or....
        if (currentRequest.Contains("ajax/book/list"))
        {
            svcPath += "/list";
        }

        int dotasmx = svcPath.IndexOf(".asmx");
        string path = svcPath.Substring(0, dotasmx + 5);
        string pathInfo = svcPath.Substring(dotasmx + 5);
        context.RewritePath(path, pathInfo, context.Request.Url.Query);
    }
```

BookWebService.asmx:

```
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [ScriptService] ///******************* Important
    public class BookWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]

        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)] ///******************* Important
        public string list()
        {
          return "Hi";

        }

     }
```

Works for me :)

Comment: Yes, it works. I added IgnoreWebServiceCall to the Global.asax only. Everything else stays the same. Thanks.